# I cannot get a result from a single line put into the Erlang shell

Tags: linux, ubuntu, erlang

I typed `erl` to start the erlang shell (Eshell V5.7.4). The shell starts. But, if I type some expression in the shell like say 20+30 and hit enter I’m back to 1>, and the result of the expression is not shown.

What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You must type : `20+30.` 
Don't forgot **DOT**.
Hope i can help you.... :D

Comment: Yes, it's the DOT which tells the Erlang reader that it has reached the end of the expression. There is no restriction on over how many lines an expression may stretch. This is the same as with function definitions in a module.