# Erlang shell cannot display the result of expression

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Erlang shell problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061328/erlang-shell-problem)

I installed erlang 5.9.2 on my macbook pro and a laptop with ubuntu. But neither of them have a same problem:

I open the terminal and type erl, i can see the version of erlang so it works well.
But I type a express like 2 + 3, i cannot see the result. just like this

```
1>2 + 3
1>

1>a = 2 + 3
1>a
1>
```

could anyone help solve this problem?

Thx a lot!

Comment: you may even get a `bad match` error with this expression: `a = 2 + 3`. Take note of what Erlang Variables are, and how they should be formatted.

Answer (score 7):

A ha, erlang need a `.` to represent the end of the expression.

```
1>2+3.
5
```

Comment: That it does! A `.` ends a function definition and and a `.` ends an expression in the shell.